# Blend mode with alpha

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, image-processing, alphablending, compute-shader

I am trying to replicate blend modes. Currently I have recreated a screen blend mode, but it doesn't seem to work really well with transparent images.

I have two textures

Image 1 (Foreground)

[image]

Image 2 (Background)

[image]

And the result I get is this

[image]

The Compute Shader code

```
#pragma kernel Blend

RWTexture2D<float4> Result;

Texture2D<float4> TopLayer;
Texture2D<float4> BottomLayer;

[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void Blend(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    if (TopLayer[id.xy].w == 0 && BottomLayer[id.xy].w > 0)
    {
        Result[id.xy] = BottomLayer[id.xy];
    }
    else if (BottomLayer[id.xy].w == 0 && TopLayer[id.xy].w > 0)
    {
        Result[id.xy] = TopLayer[id.xy];
    }
    else if (BottomLayer[id.xy].w == 0 && TopLayer[id.xy].w == 0)
    {
        Result[id.xy] = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        float alpha_final = BottomLayer[id.xy].w + TopLayer[id.xy].w - BottomLayer[id.xy].w * TopLayer[id.xy].w;

        float4 tex = 1 - (1 - TopLayer[id.xy]) * (1 - BottomLayer[id.xy]);

        Result[id.xy] = float4(tex.x, tex.y, tex.z, alpha_final);
    }
}
```

How do I blend images with different alphas properly?

Comment: It sure what output you are looking for, but my guess is that you want to use alpha as a weight in the blending.

Comment: I have multiplied each layer color by its alpha like so float4 tex = 1 - (1 - TopLayer[id.xy] * TopLayer[id.xy].w) * (1 - BottomLayer[id.xy] * BottomLayer[id.xy].w); It looks better now, although, I'm not sure if it's 100% correct. It looks like I'm using normal mode. Like I'm adding one layer on top of another. Is this the way to do it? To add weight

Comment: Well, most of your second image is transparent. You might need a more complex input to see differences between blend modes.

Comment: I've tried implementing same approach with the color dodge and multiply modes. Color dodge seems to result in similar result as in e.g. Photoshop, I'll have to do some more testing, however multiply results are definitely incorrect. I use this equation (TopLayer[id.xy] * TopLayer[id.xy].w) * (BottomLayer[id.xy] * BottomLayer[id.xy].w); The blending seems to be on point I think but the more transparent that fade image goes the more dark the background image becomes. I guess it's because multiplying the color by low alpha darkens the pixel color, but how do I blend it properly then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blending with alpha channels requires weighting with the alpha value.

I hadn’t before thought of how to properly weight in the screen blend case, which is a multiplicative composition. I think it makes sense to do it like a [weighted geometric mean](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_geometric_mean): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_geometric_mean): raise the multiplicands to the power of the corresponding weight (the alpha value), then raise the result to the power of the inverse of the sum of weights. Because we want to replicate the standard case when both alphas are 1:

1 - (1-a) (1-b)

which doesn’t have a square root in it, we will divide the sum of alpha values by 2:

1 - [ (1-a)<sup>wa</sup> (1-b)<sup>wb</sup> ] <sup>2/(wa+wb)</sup>

The output alpha channel itself could be computed in the same way, or could be a simple maximum of the two alpha values. I don’t know what would look better.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I got it working with screen and color dodge. I blended different images and got accurate results! However, I am unable to get the multiply mode working. The transparent areas result in black. :/

Comment: @UnknownUser: if both wa and wb are 0, then 2/(wa+wb) is infinity, which you might want to avoid. You should special-case that situation. I don’t know if raising to the power of infinity is handled correctly in your environment.

Comment: I have found this alpha composite equation: 
(1 - fgA / a) * bgC + (fgA / a) * round((1 - bgA) * fgC + bgA * bC); and have used it for every color channel like so 

alphaCompose(BottomLayer[id.xy].w, TopLayer[id.xy].w, a, BottomLayer[id.xy].x, TopLayer[id.xy].x, TopLayer[id.xy].x * BottomLayer[id.xy].x); 

It fixes the issue although the blended result is too dark in comparison to Photoshop result